# Carrinho de compras

Tags: vb.net

Estou a realizar a minha *PAP*, e estou com o seguinte problema:

Vou ter um formulário em que vou ter uma *DataGridView* com as peças, e quero que ao clicar duas vezes em cima da peça que pretendo comprar, insira para uma *ListView* onde posteriormente irá fazer o *Insert* na base de dados.

Gostaria que me dessem uma ajuda, qual é a melhor *Tool* para fazer isso, uma *ListBox* ou uma *DataGridView*?

Answer (score 0):

Se você for apenas visualizar os dados, a melhor opção seria a ListView. Agora caso você deseje alterar ou manipular os dados de outra forma, a melhor opção é a gridView

Pelo que entendi, você usará apenas para visualização, e posteriormente inserção no banco de dados, então neste caso a listView será melhor.